# WiX 32bit and 64bit in single bundle, duplicate ID

Tags: wix

**What:**
How can I get a `PackageGroupRef` to contain multiple `MsiPackage` or `ExePackage` with different sources depending on 32bit/64bit `Detect/InstallCondition`?

**Tried:**
If the two MsiPackage Id are ommitted or the same I get duplicate symbol error.

> Error 2 Duplicate symbol 'ChainPackage:SQLSysClrTypes.msi' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.

If the two Ids are set and different, I get `"An expected identifier was not found"`

**Source:**

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2012ClrTypes" After="NetFx45Web" />
  ...
</Chain>
```

...

```
<Fragment>
  <PackageGroup Id="Sql2012ClrTypes">
    <!-- x64 -->
    <!-- Unique Ids here cause 'expected id not found' error -->
    <MsiPackage DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 CLR Types"
                Cache="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"
                InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND VersionNT64" />

    <!-- x86 -->    
    <!-- Unique Ids here cause 'expected id not found' error -->
    <MsiPackage DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 CLR Types"
                Cache="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"
                InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND NOT VersionNT64" />
  </PackageGroup>    
</Fragment>
```

**EDIT:**

I think this works, is there a better solution?

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>

    <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2012ClrTypes" After="NetFx45Web" />
    <?else ?>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2012ClrTypesx86" After="NetFx45Web" />
    <?endif ?>
</Chain>
```

...

```
<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="Sql2012ClrTypes">
      <MsiPackage Id="Sql2012ClrTypes"
                  DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 CLR Types"
                  Cache="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"
                  InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND VersionNT64" />
    </PackageGroup>
    <PackageGroup Id="Sql2012ClrTypesx86">
      <MsiPackage Id="Sql2012ClrTypesx86"
                  DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 CLR Types"
                  Cache="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"
                  InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND NOT VersionNT64" />
    </PackageGroup>    
  </Fragment>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you have an Id attribute specified for either of the two MsiPackage elements, so it's defaulting to `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` for both of the packages. Try adding an `Id` attribute to each.

Comment: I tried just didnt leave it in the code there: "If the two Ids are set and different, I get "An expected identifier was not found""